# count all the characters I have used in a textbox c#

Tags: c#

I want to calculate all the number of characters I have used in a textbox.
For example: If I write this equation in textbox:
5x-2(3y+2)*3y(8)
so what code or line should I write for counting all the parenthesis used here?

Comment: What is your question `what code or line should I write for counting all the parenthesis used here?` or `count all the characters I have used in a textbox` or something else?

Comment: what code or line should I write for counting all the parenthesis used here(textbox)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the **total amount** of characters in a text box you can simply use `TextLength`

e.g.

```
var totalAmountOfCharacters = textBox1.TextLength.ToString();
```

To get a **specific character count** you can use `Count`

e.g.

```
var open = textBox1.Text.Count(x => x == '(');
var close = textBox1.Text.Count(x => x == ')');

var total = open + close;
```

*or*

```
var total = textBox1.Text.Count(x => x == '(' || x ==')');
```

Comment: i don't want to display all the characters but those specific which i have used

Comment: Since your original post indicates two questions ... my answer is updated with two available answers. One for all characters and one for specific characters.

Comment: 2nd eg works for my code.. thanks :)

Comment: @haishSee if this is the correct answer to you're question then mark the correct answer as correct answer please.

Answer (score 1):

String is a sequence of characters, so just use this

```
textbox.Text.Count(c => c == '(' || c == ')');
```

A little bit complex way, but more elegant:

```
var charCount = textbox.Text
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

var parenthesisCount = charCount['('] + charCount[')']; // 4
var yCount = charCount['y']; // 2
```

Comment: `Value` is not even a definition of the `TextBox` class. Unbelievable this gets an up vote ...

Comment: @jim yeap, I used WinForms a lot of time ago, and do not remember exactly what the name of property is. The answer is right, similar to your and given earlier. What the problem that property name not valid? BTW This is the big issue of SO - a lot of people wants to get no-thinking-required answer, and do not want to turn on their head even to understand that Value should be the Text.

Comment: understand what you mean, but somebody that asks a question like this is very new to programming, so hes going to have a big problem using a wrong definition ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expressions (Regexp) to count anything that you need, including multiple characters at one time

```
Regex.Matches(input, @"\)|\(").Count
```

This example counts the matches of ( and ) symbols.

Comment: Very readable solution :)

Comment: You have to escape the parenthesis.

Comment: @Slai, nope, doesn't work that way

Comment: not working. I'm working on c# windows forms application

Comment: Updated the answer. Added @ to escape the string.

Answer (score 0):

I found it a bit interesting that there are 7 separate Unicode categories in that expression.

```
var s = "5x-2(3y+2)*3y(8)";
var l = s.ToLookup(char.GetUnicodeCategory);

foreach (var g in l)
    Debug.Print($"{g.Key,20} {g.Count()}: {string.Join(" ", g)}");
```

prints:

```
  DecimalDigitNumber 6: 5 2 3 2 3 8
     LowercaseLetter 3: x y y
     DashPunctuation 1: -
     OpenPunctuation 2: ( (
          MathSymbol 1: +
    ClosePunctuation 2: ) )
    OtherPunctuation 1: *
```

Answer (score -1):

var strEquation=textbox1.Text; //5x-2(3y+2)*3y(8)

```
int x = strEquation.Count(c => Char.IsNumber(c)); // 6
int y = strEquation.Count(c => Char.IsLetter(c)); // 3
int z = strEquation.Count(c => Char.Equals('(')); // 4

int total=x+y+z;
```

Let me know if it works?

Comment: It works. It gives the answer 9. but could you explain me this? c => Char.IsNumber(c)

Comment: What its doing is going to each character on strEquation and checking character "c" is number or letter if its true incrementing the count..at the end returning the total result.  linq expression instead of for loop.

Comment: @Nishantverma your answer is giving amount of numbers and amount of letters. OP's question is amount of parenthesis.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for pointing I missed that line of code :)